# Calculate limit value of sequence by inequation with integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, integral-inequality

I have to calculate the limit of the sequence

$a_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k}$ .

To do so, I have to show that the following inequation is true:

$\int_{n+1}^{2n+1} \frac{dx}{x} \leqslant a_n \leqslant \int_{n}^{2n} \frac{dx}{x}$

The excercise gives the following hint: *"Find appropriate limits for the integrals"*.

I know, how I calculate the limit of the sequence (without the inequation). But I don't know, how I have to show the inequation. Has anyone a hint witch limits I have to choose to show the inequation? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Use $$\int_{n+k}^{n+k+1}\frac{dx}x\leqslant\frac1{n+k}\leqslant\int_{n+k-1}^{n+k}{}{}\frac{dx}x.$$

Comment: I get it now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: We have $$\int_{n+1}^{2n+1}\frac{dx}{x}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{n+k}^{n+k+1}\frac{dx}{x}
 $$ and $$\int_{n}^{2n}\frac{dx}{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{n+k}^{n+k+1}\frac{dx}{x}$$ and $1/x$ is a decreasing function when $x$ grows.

Comment: Wow. Cool idea. I had difficulties to understand why these two are equal, but now I see it. Thank you!